# How to use Mui Tooltip to wrap Autocomplete

Tags: material-ui

This is the working example of using Autocomplete
https://codesandbox.io/s/xktzhv?file=/demo.tsx

How to make this work wrapped in a mui tooltip?

This is my example of that Autocomplete example but wrapped in a Mui tooltip, and it doesn't populate the options.

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-microservice-p6xlpq?file=/demo.tsx

How to fix?